# How can the arctan2 function be calculated for time?

Tags: python, trigonometry

So, I am trying to calculate the solution of the transcendental equation of the form:

```
a*cos(t)+b*sin(t)= c*cos(t)+d*sin(t)
```

for t which can be re-caste as:

```
tan(t)=(a-b)/(d-c)
```

Now, one can simply use the `arctan2` of Numpy but the result is between `[-pi/2,pi/2]` whereas t is time and cannot be negative.

Which function of Numpy do I use to find only the positive solutions for the above two equations?

A better way to put this is:
What type of arctan function do I use so that I  get the value in between `[0,pi]`

Comment: This is a question for [maths.se], the fact you're doing the equation in python doesnt feel relevant

Comment: I want to know what version of tan do I use so that it gives me positive solutions of the equation.

Comment: @Sayse. I think you missed the point of the question entirely

Comment: @MadPhysicist - Quite possible, I read it as trying to assign limits to an equation

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to post-process the result array and add 2pi to the negative values.

Comment: @JuanR why 2pi and not pi? The period of tan is pi

Comment: @Lost to convert from negative angle (say -pi/2) to the positive one (3/2 pi).

Comment: @JuanR Yes I understand that but why 2*pi ? Why not pi which when added to -pi/2 gives pi/2 a positive number ?

Comment: @Lost I don't think that would be accurate. If you rotate a vector 360 degrees it will result in the same vector. If you rotate it 180 degrees it would be a vector with the same modulus but pointing in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. Which one you select depends on the physical meaning of the inputs and solution.

1. Discard negative inputs (if either `a < b` or `d <= c`, but not both): there is no possible answer.
2. Wrap negative angles to the positive side by adding `pi`.

Since you don't care about quadrants, you can use `np.arctan` instead of `np.arctan2`. Pre-computing the ratio will make it easier to check on option #1.

Comment: Why add   2 * pi when pi is the period of tan?

Comment: Also, why should I ignore the d=c case? arctan would return float(inf) right or would that be an error?

Comment: @Lost that would be a divide by zero, which would be a ask error or a warning with NaN in the result. You could run a test yourself

Comment: and what about adding pi instead of 2*pi?